# Adding .dat data to a C struct?

Tags: c, file-io

So i have to a quick thing in C and need so guidance, as i don't use C normally.

I have City.dat file with some data in it (i simplified it StackOverflow):

```
Postal-Code | City 
32            San Diego
```

In my City.h file i created the struct for it:

```
typedef struct{

    int postalCode;
    char cityName;
} City;


typedef struct {
    City **city;
} CityList;
```

How would should i approach the iteration in City.c to collect all data from city.dat? Obviously, i need a for loop, but i would like to see an example how to read the data from the dat file and print out the collected cities?

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you are at a point where you do not know how to read from file in C, you should start with a tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_working_with_files.htm If there is something specific about this file that gives you trouble, you should specify it. If you expect someone on this site to write the whole assignment code for you, you are on the wrong site. Good luck!

Comment: @LevM.: I decided to treat this as not homework. While I don't really know, he says the problem's been reduced so he won't be able to copy/paste any answers. Then I gave the full fluent answer. If this is dropped in homework, it will stand out like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char cityName;
```

really should be

```
char *cityName;
```

We could actually use a flexible array here but we won't because your real structure may have more than one string.

Gather loop is easy.

```
#define SPLIT 15

// Stupid helper function to read a single line no matter how long.
// Really should be in the standard library but isn't.
static int readline(FILE *h, char **buf, size_t *nbuf)
{
    if (!*buf) {
        *buf = malloc(128);
        nbuf = 128;
    }
    size_t offset = 0;
    do {
        if (offset + 1 >= *nbuf) {
            // Just keep growing the line buffer until we have enough room.
            size_t nbuf2 = *nbuf << 1;
            char *buf2 = realloc(*buf, nbuf2);
            if (!buf2) return -1;
            *buf = buf2;
            *nbuf = nbuf2;
        }
        if (!fgets(buf + offset, *nbuf - offset, h)) return -1;
        offset += strlen(buf + offset);
    } while (offset > 0 && buf[offset - 1] == '\n');
    return 0;
}

CityList readfile(const char *file);
{
    errno = 0; // Check errno for short read.
    FILE *f = fopen(file);
    if (!f) return NULL;
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t nbuf = 0;
    City **cities = NULL;
    size_t ncities;
    size_t acities;
    if (readline(f, &buf, &nbuf)) return NULL; // get rid of header line
    acities = 4;
    ncities = 0;
    cities = malloc(acities * sizeof(City**));
    if (!cities) return NULL;
    cities[0] = NULL; // Mark list empty
    while (!readline(f, &buf, &nbuf)) {
        // get new city struct
        int n = strtol(buf);
        int len = strlen(buf);
        if (len > 0 && buf[len] == '\n') buf[len--] = 0; // Cut off trailing \n
        if (len + 1 > SPLIT) /* validity check */ {
            if (ncities + 1 == acities) {
                size_t ncities2 = ncities << 1;
                City **cities2 = realloc(ncities 2 * sizeof (City**));
                if (!cities2) break;
            }
            // Allocate the entire struct and its data all at once.
            char *citybuf = malloc(sizeof(City*) + sizeof(City) + len - SPLIT + 1);
            City **city = (City*)citybuf;
            // Slot all the stuff into the structure
            city[0] = citybuf + sizeof(City *);
            city[0]->postalCode = n; // Value saved from above.
            city[0]->cityName = citybuf + sizeof(City *) + sizeof(City);
            strcpy(city[0]->cityName, buf + SPLIT);
            // Add city to list
            cities[ncities] = city;
            cities[++ncities] = NULL; // Mark end of list
        }
    }
    free(buf);
    fclose(f);
    CityList l = { cities };
    return l
}
```

When you come to free this; every entry in CityList needs to be freed until you come to the terminating `NULL`. The allocation allocated the subpointer, the struct, and the struct contents all at once, so there's only one `free` call per city.

Particular points of interest: The buffer is parsed into chunks early. Then the city structure is allocated all at once since we can look at the structure elements and say how much space we need. This is idiomatic to do it this way if the records themselves are not edited after being read in, as the code is both shorter and faster. I got annoyed trying to figure out how to handle errors and just said read `errno` which does work, but some people don't like code that clears `errno`. On the happy path, clearing `errno` is fine. It's only on the error paths that it causes a problem.

I have not ran this code. It might have bugs.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for as a starting guide. Thank you!